# Files in Cron not running

Tags: cron

I added 2 files to my crontab and I am trying to make them run every minute but can not figure out what is wrong. I tried to follow steps online and thought I did everything the same as in the tutorial.

```
1 * * * * /Desktop/wget/fb_BQ_GCS2.py
1 * * * * /Desktop/wget/postslack3.py
~                                          

1 * * * * /Desktop/fb_BQ_GCS2.py
1 * * * * /Desktop/postslack3.py
~
```

I have tried both of these and still get nothing. The only thing I can think of is that maybe I have an error in my path and in can not find the files? First time using Cron so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to my question. In order to run a python script through cron you need to add Python to the beginning of the command. See code below for examples.

```
*/1 * * * * python ~/Desktop/fb_BQ_GCS2.py
*/1 * * * * python ~/Desktop/postslack3.py
```